# Вызов функции на C/C++ из программы на Asm

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, sasm

При компиляции в SASM (IDE для ASM) на NASM выдает ошибку:    `C:\.....\SASM\program.o:C:\....\Ap:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to 'BubbleSort'`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?
Код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int *BubbleSort(int* m)
{
    for (int i = sizeof(m) - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (m[j] > m[j + 1])
            {
                int foo = m[j];
                m[j] = m[j + 1];
                m[j + 1] = foo;
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(m); ++i)
        cout << m[i] << endl;
    return m;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Код на ASM (в IDE SASM):

```
    %include "io.inc"

    section .data
        mas db 2, 7, 3, 2, 1 

    section .text

    extern _BubbleSort

    global CMAIN
    CMAIN:
        mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging

        mov edx, [mas]
        call _BubbleSort

        push    EBP
        mov     EBP, ESP      

    mov eax,[ebp+4]     ; get the address of the array
    mov ebp, eax        ; BP now points to the array
    mov eax, [ebp]      ; get value of first element
    add eax,[ebp+2]     ;   add remaining elements
    add eax,[ebp+4]

    pop EBP
ret
```

Comment: По делу: скорей всего линкеру не передал имя объектника полученного из С++ файла, как именно сделать это средствами IDE — не отвечу. Остальные ошибки: Функция в принципе не рабочая (см. что такое указатель и что такое массив; sizeof(m) равен 8 или 4 не зависимо от размера массива); Почему значение передаётся в EDX? Если дело на amd64, то должно быть в RCX, если на x86, то в стеке; Если нет особой необходимости, то для начала проще экспериментировать с Си, а не C++.